# Enabling Functions in a Config file for script to run Bash Shellscript

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a configuration file where I am exporting variables that can enable and run certain functions in my bash shell script. I was wondering the best way to accomplish this. My thought was just to use a for loop and do a simple if else - not sure if there is a better way. Any suggestions?

Example exported variables in config (I don't have to do it like the following but this was what I was thinking):

```
data_error_check_run=TRUE
check_ctl_dat_exists_run=FALSE
check_ctl_dat_format_run=TRUE
ctl_dat_count_check_run=TRUE
mask_field_run=FALSE
custom_target_file_run=TRUE
```

Functions inside script to run:

```
data_error_check
check_ctl_dat_exists
check_ctl_dat_format
ctl_dat_count_check
mask_field $MASK_FILE
custom_target_file $CUSTOM_CONFIG
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to run the functions only when the corresponding variable is set to TRUE? I would do something like

```
[[ "$data_error_check_run" == TRUE ]]     && data_error_check
[[ "$check_ctl_dat_exists_run" == TRUE ]] && check_ctl_dat_exists
[[ "$mask_field_run" == TRUE ]]           && mask_field "$MASK_FILE"
```

`[[` doesn't barf on unset variables so not setting a specific one is the same as setting it to `FALSE`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Just out of curiosity: for which values of the variables are the quotes really necessary here?

Comment: At least `$MASK_FILE`. The others may not need quotes, but I added them out of habit. Please feel free to roll back the edit if you wish.